# How I can convert date to following format in Shell?

Tags: shell, date, date-formatting

I am passing a date as an argument and needed to convert it in given format in shell.

Pasting the sample code here

```
echo "20190101120001" | xargs date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -u
```

And this should display output as

```
Tue Jan 01 12:00:01 UTC 2019
```

Comment: The `+` argument *is* the output format; you appear to be treating it as an *input* format.

Comment: Why the `echo | xargs` fuss, vs just passing the value directly?

Comment: I wanted to convert in specific format for the given input. Correct me if I am using wrong method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="20190101120001"
date -d "${str:0:8} ${str:8:2}:${str:10:2}:${str:12:2}" -u
```

Comment: If the answer is helping you to find the solution, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and mark with a green hook, thx.